# Angular6 Custom PopUp

Tags: angular, angular6

I Am trying to make a popup window having input fields and buttons. following is the code

**Parent Component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onClickEa()">Add </button>           
</div>
```

**Parent component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ConfigPopupComponent } from '../config-popup/config-popup.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-providerservice',
    templateUrl: './providerservice.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./providerservice.component.css']
})
export class ProviderserviceComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
     constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.open();
    }
    open() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfigPopupComponent);

  }
}
```

**popup component.html**

```
<div>
   popup worked
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ConfigPopupComponent } from './config-popup/config-popup.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'xeservice', component: XeserviceComponent },
  {path: 'providerservice', component: ProviderserviceComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent,
    XeserviceComponent,
    EaConfigPopupComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FormsModule,

  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  entryComponents: [ ConfigPopupComponent ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I click on the add button from the parent view child component should be show as a popup. previously i had some error at that time I added popup component as an entry component.but still  have the error. 
[image]
anybody, please help

Comment: I think you'll find the solution to your problem here: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2001

Comment: More importantly check how the imports are done in the above mentioned link. I believe imports are the issue here.

Comment: i have tried this too. but getting an error=>NgbModalBackdrop_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value:.tTried set time out niside ngAfterViewInit.Still not working

Answer (score 1):

**You misspelt your component name.**

You imported it as:

```
import { ConfigPopupComponent } from '../config-popup/config-popup.component';
```

and used it as:

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(EaConfigPopupComponent); // see this component is not imported
```

See the component name is different. You have not imported this component.

> **So, change it to:**

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfigPopupComponent);
```

Comment: import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; Import NgbModule in app.module.ts.

Comment: Again in your app.module.ts You have imported EaConfigPopupComponent and in the entryComponents added ConfigPopupComponent. What does it mean? You misspelt it or something else!

Comment: You can find a working demo here. https://stackblitz.com/angular/brrobnxnooox?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: is it possible to  make ng-template as a separate component?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Put ng-template code in the separate component and pass the required data.

Comment: when i debug showing  Reference Error: ariaLabelledBy is not defined"

Comment: Please make a new question with the code so that we can help you more.